# Django Test - Multiple Databases not being created?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm trying to test out multiple database routing in django but I'm running into some errors. In my `settings.py` I have:

```
 if TESTING:
     DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
            'NAME': 'test',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': 'testpassword',
        ...
        },
        'primary': {
             'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
             'NAME': 'test',
             'USER': 'test',
             'PASSWORD': 'testpassword',
        ....
        }
    }
```

and a view that requires changes to be done on the 'primary' database:

```
@transaction.atomic('primary')
def my_view(request):
  ... do stuff on primary db table
```

this works fine with my configuration in production (i have a db router that routes all write requests to the primary and a replica for reading) but when I run my test suite this view fails with `django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection primary doesn't exist`

how can i get django to create this db in testing? or do i need to do some additional aliasing / routing in my test settings? thanks!